# moving elements from one dataframe to another in a non-parralel fashion

Tags: r

I want to move elements from one dataframe to another but my usual bind functions are letting me down in this instance. I want to move elements in a way that I can illustrate below.

```
   df1           df2
  1   a         1   a
  1   a         2   b
  2   b         3   c
  2   b         4   d
  2   b         5   e
  3   c         6   f
```

So, I want to move the elements from the df2[,2] onto the second column of the first dataframe in this way. If it makes it any clearer, specifically my second dataframe's rows indicate each household, whereas the first indicates for each individual, with the number indicating in df1[,1] indicating which household each row belongs to. I want to move info from the household to each individual.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Why not just assign i.e. `df1[,3] <- df2[,2]`

Comment: I think you want to perform a merge, using the first column as index? In that case the function `merge()` should help (or `left_join()` in the package `dplyr`).